# node app on aws elastic beanstalk; Node Command setting results in command not found

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to start my application with a different file; not app.js or server.js, and I don't want to add a start script to npm as there's several possible configurations for this application. In the elastic beanstalk console, under Configuration -> Software Configuration, there's a Node command setting, and I'm setting the value to the file I want, like:

```
eb_server.js
```

and also tried `node eb_server.js`

But in the nodejs logs on the app server (/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log, I get this output:

```
sh: eb_server.js: command not found
```

My question is what's the proper way to set the alternative start script command using the elastic beanstalk console?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's not meant for a node command directly, but rather an npm command. You can specify "npm run ", where you can call the custom node start command, pointing to whatever file you want. Naming is hard... ;-)

Comment: I even tried `npm run deploy`, still EB runs `npm start`, and since I've removed `npm start`, it throws error saying that start command not found.